# Convert records between patterns to one record per line

Tags: regex, awk, sed, multiline

I have a file which looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
Record                                                : 1
SomeValue                                             : foo1
SomeOtherValue                                        : bar1
NthValue                                              : 1234

----------------------------------------------------------
Record                                                : 2
SomeValue                                             : foo2
SomeOtherValue                                        : bar2
NthValue                                              : 2234

----------------------------------------------------------
Record                                                : 1
SomeValue                                             : foo3
SomeOtherValue                                        : bar3
NthValue                                              : 3234
```

And I want to convert it so that each record (delimited by the string of dashes) lives on its own line thus:

```
Record : 1 SomeValue : foo1 SomeOtherValue : bar1 NthValue : 1234
Record : 2 SomeValue : foo2 SomeOtherValue : bar2 NthValue : 4321
Record : 1 SomeValue : foo3 SomeOtherValue : bar3 NthValue : 0000
```

I can't for the life of me work out how to do it with a simple command without resorting to a script. Any help here would be much appreciated.

The delimiter string is always the same, by the way, but the number and size of fields within each record can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let `gawk` do it itself by recalculating the fields:

```
gawk -v RS="----------------------------------------------------------" '{$1=$1} NF>1' file
```

Or, setting `RS` to multiple `-`s in general as Ed Morton suggests:

```
gawk -v RS="-+" '{$1=$1} NF>1' file
```

In both cases you get:

```
Record : 1 SomeValue : foo1 SomeOtherValue : bar1 NthValue : 1234
Record : 2 SomeValue : foo2 SomeOtherValue : bar2 NthValue : 2234
Record : 1 SomeValue : foo3 SomeOtherValue : bar3 NthValue : 3234
```

When you change a field in the record, `awk` rebuilds `$0`, takes all fields and concats them together separated by OFS, which is a space by default.

Comment: You should state it's gawk specific due to multi-char RS and you could reduce that setting to `-v RS='-+'` or `-v RS='-{N}'` (whetever N is) or similar.